# Why is my table displayed at the top of the page?

Tags: floats

I figure this must be a common issue but I could not find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    Text: This text should be above the table, but it is not.
    \begin{table}
        Table: This table should be below the text, but it is not.  
    \end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Why is the table at the top? Thanks!

Comment: This is the absolute worst thing about LaTeX.  Why is [h!] even an option if it just ignores it?!  This afternoon I had a report that ended with a half a page of slack, but LaTeX insisted on sticking my table at the top of the page regardless of [h!] and all the extra room.  Thanks for asking, the float package suggested here fixed everything!

Comment: @Noah Thanks for sharing that. Yes, I believe this is a common issue for plenty of LaTeX users.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`table` is a *floating* environment. TeX has special rules for placing floats so that they cause minimal disruption of the surrounding text.

You can give LaTeX hints of how to place your floats. For example, to make LaTeX try to place it where you inserted it, specify the option `h` (for “here”):

```
\begin{table}[h]
    Table: This table should be below the text, but it is not.  
\end{table}
```

Note that this won’t always work because LaTeX still tries to make the text look *nice*. Your hint is only that: a hint, not a definite command.

You can force LateX to obey your command to place a floating environment HERE by loading the package `float` and specifying the option `H` (capital letter!):

```
\begin{table}[H]
    Table: This table should be below the text, but it is not.  
\end{table}
```

But notice that this can lead to an ugly layout.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph♦: Thanks, I don't have enough rep to up vote your answer. But it was helpful! [h] worked fine for me but [H] was not very good at all - the table were placed on a new page - so you were right, I got a pretty ugly layout!

Comment: @AD. If `[H]` placed the table on a new page, you did something wrong. Perhaps you forgot to load the `float` package?

Comment: even if you use [H], if there isn't enough room left on the page for the table, it can go to the next page.  i can't explain why [h] might fit it in, but [H] won't.

Comment: @barbara: That’s my point though: there might not be enough room, but then neither should `[h]` work. Or is that a mistake and `[h]` actually works in cases where `[H]` doesn’t?

Comment: i've skimmed enough of the float package documentation (texdoc float) to determine that some internal macros are redefined.  i don't have enough time to compare the code (or, more likely, run a debugging session on a small example) to determine the actual differences, but i do suspect that the effects are not quite identical with respect to penalties and spacing, which might be just enough to make a difference.  still a puzzlement.

Comment: If you just use [h], then you get a warning that [h] was changed to [ht] if it cannot fit here: LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.

Comment: +1 Now, three year later, I have enough reputation to up vote. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 14):

To quote the [FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats):

> Tables and figures have a tendency to *surprise*, by floating away from where they were specified to appear....

Read the FAQ to learn how to control the placement of your tables.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks, I don't have enough rep to up vote your answer. But it was helpful!

Comment: +1 Now, three year later, I have enough reputation to up vote. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 0):

[h] is definitely working out. Please try it. After using this, you can keep the table beneath the sentence/paragraph.