# Reference to a table before it appears

Tags: cross-referencing, floats

I want to reference a table before it appears.The TeX code is pasted below

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The results given in Table~\ref{tab:a} show the  performance of
the class.

\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lrc}\hline
        Name & Mark & Grade \\
        \hline
        Prasad & 99 & A+ \\
        Prakash & 51 & C\\
        Shine & 5 & F\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Class Mark List}\label{tab:a}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the text

```
The results given in Table~\ref{tab:a} show the  performance of
    the class.
```

is coming after the table. How can I put the table immediately after the text.

Comment: Is this a problem of where the table appears (float placement) or of referencing it? You can influence the placement of the table with a modifier `\begin{table}[h]`. (I believe the `\label` should go inside the `\caption`.)

Comment: @Christian: The `\label` just needs to go after the `\caption`. I can't think of any good reason to put it inside it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my table displayed at the top of the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/why-is-my-table-displayed-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Comment: @Christian. I want the table to be referenced before **and** place the table immediately after the text.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrc}\hline
        ....
    \caption{Class Mark List}\label{tab:a}
\end{table}
```

However, from typographers view the caption of a table should be above the tabular.

Comment: @Vinod: I know, but in other situations not and it is already modified internally to [ht]

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{table}[htdp]
\vskip 0.25cm
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c| c |c |}
\hline\hline
{\textcolor{blue}{Plasma Parameter} & {\textcolor{blue}{PIC code parameters }& { \textcolor{blue}{MHD code parameters}}&\\
\hline
{\bf B$_z$}& 0.2&6.5 (nT)\\
\hline
{\bf V$_x$}& 0.25 & 500 (km.sec$^-^1$)\\
\hline
{\bf V$_A$}& 0.028 & 63 (km.sec$^-^1$)\\
\hline
$\frac{V_{A}}{V_{SW}}$&0.11&0.12\\
\hline
{\bf M$_A$}&8.9&7.8\\
\hline
{M$_S_C$}&5.5&5.2\\
\hline
\beta&1.6&2.7\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\caption{ PIC and MHD simulations}\label{Tab:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you provide some explanations? Also, it would be better to have a full compilable code instead of just a snippet.

Comment: The code do not compile, could you please add the details to make it compilable? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks! It works! \label should be put after \caption .